# List independent of surrounding list

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want that a list that is inside a list ignores that it is the second level of depth:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item C
    \item D
    \end{enumerate}
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

should give me something like:

> 1.A
>
> 1.C
>
> 2.D
>
> 2.B

I don't want to change the definition of enumii...

Is there an easy way to tell the second (inside) list that it should be a list of level 1?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What should happen if there are more items in the nested list? Should there be no indent and the item number be the same?

Comment: I added a second item to this list. It should just count from 1 to n.

Comment: No indentation? Sorry, but I don't understand. Even less after reading your comment to cmhughes' answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy with the `enumitem` package.

You have to set `[label=\arabic*.]` as options for the outer `enumerate` and `[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt]` for the inner one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\item A
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item C
    \item D
    \end{enumerate}
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\arabic*)}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
% arara: pdflatex 
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\arabic*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item C
    \end{enumerate}
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats of cause possible, but is it also possible to tell the second list that it is "first level"?
With your example one would have a problem when there is a second 2 level list where the second list should be like 1.1, 1.2. and so on...

Comment: @mimi just to clarify: you'd like one instance of a second level `enumerate` to behave in one way, and another instance to behave in another?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Enumerate}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[Enumerate]{label=\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
    \begin{Enumerate}
    \item C
    \item D
    \end{Enumerate}
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you do not want to mess with the second level list, then make a different env.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\def\nest{%
\edef\reset{\c@enumi\the\c@enumi\relax}\c@enumi\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\nest
%    \begin{enumerate}
    \item C
    \item D
\reset
%    \end{enumerate}
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmmm.  if this were to be cross-referenced without benefit of hyperlinking, i would be *very* confused.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am confused as well, but presumably the OP asked for it for a reason.